# I transferred coins to an address that belongs to ETH wallet instead of ETC

Tags: wallets, addresses, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic, localbitcoins

I have a problem. so, Ask for help.
by mistake, I transferred coins to an address that belongs to ETH wallet instead of ETC.
Is ther a solution for this?
Pleas, see below.

Answer (score 3):

Since ETH and ETC have the same underlying protocols for address generation, the addresses will work on either chain. As long as you control the private key for the ETH address you sent the ETC to, you should be able to import that private key in whatever ETC wallet you use and you will have access to the funds.

If you do not control the private key for the ETH address you sent the ETC to, you won't be able to recover them.